# AttributeError with Flumotion

Tags: python

I'm trying to make a VOD server with Flumotion.
I know that Flumotion is deprecated and my error comes from an obsolete call in Python, but I didn't find anything else like flumotion.

My server is running on a Debian 8.4.

Here is the error I have when I want to launch the flumotion-worker:

```
AttributeError: 'EPollReactor' object has no attribute 'listenWith'
```

There was a patch for this error but all the links are dead.

Does someone has a link for the patch or an idea (how to resolve this or an other way to do a VOD server?)?

Thanks!

Comment: Please add the full error traceback to your question by editing it.

Comment: `dir(module_name)` is always a good place to start when you get a non-obvious `AttributeError`

Answer (score 0):

It [appears](https://code.flumotion.com/trac/browser/README) flumotion depends on [Twisted](https://twistedmatrix.com/).

You can either:

1. find and install a version of Twisted with which flumotion is compatible
2. update flumotion to be compatible with the version of Twisted you are trying to use
3. try a completely different approach; it appears that flumotion was last updated in 2012. It is likely quite useless unless you have the resources to pick up where the previous developers left off and bring it up-to-date with the past four years of changes in the libraries and platforms it requires.  If you do get past this error, I expect you'll run into compatibility issues with gstreamer too.

Related resources:

- [Twisted ticket #367: 'Deprecate connectWith and listenWith'](https://twistedmatrix.com/trac/ticket/367)
- [Launchpad bug #1200954: Flumotion does not start: AttributeError: 'EPollReactor' object has no attribute 'listenWith'](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/flumotion/+bug/1200954)
- [Flumotion ticket #1561](https://code.flumotion.com/trac/ticket/1561)